# Connecting to a remote host syntax

Tags: c#, ports, remote-connection

In c# when I use the code :

```
 public System.IAsyncResult BeginConnect(System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state)
```

I declare the EndPoint with the ip-address of the remote host am communicating with and a port number. In this case the port number represents a port on my system or on the remote host??

Comment: The grammar on this question needs some work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect to a **remote endpoint** so the port is the port on **remote** machine.

Comment: so if I send a broadcast message then would the port number specified for the IPEndPoint represent the port number on all remote hosts??

Comment: AFAIK, yes, the same port for all machines.